# How to change the resolution Windows sends to VGA monitor?

Tags: windows, windows-10, resolution, vga, aspect-ratio

I'm using an old 1280x1024 LCD monitor with my laptop and today my VGA to HDMI adapter stopped working, so I started using VGA directly (wasn't using before because of this problem)

For some reason Windows 10 thinks the monitor is 1600x1200 and sends this signal to the monitor, which makes things look squished and a bit blurred, but fills the whole screen.

[image]

If I select 1280x1024 in the menu, it will now squish even more the screen, leaving a black bar to the right of it and manual monitor adjustments can't go all the way to the end of it.

How can I make Windows realise the actual factory resolution of the monitor through VGA?

- Windows 10
- Samsung SyncMaster 732n Plus

Thanks

Comment: Most VGA monitors have a vertical and horizontal scan adjustment on the monitor itself. VGA has no concept of "native" resolution.

Comment: Have you updated your graphic card drivers?

Comment: @Mokubai, I tried the automatic adjustment and it didn't work

Comment: Then try the manual adjustment? [Your manual](https://www.samsung.com/my/support/model/LS17PEASF/XME/) say you can adjust horizontal and vertical alignment so try that.

Comment: @LeRouteur, I did update the drivers

Comment: I've just found the solution. I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Go to Display adaptor and select from the list

So, I found the solution. Here goes the steps:

First, put the resolution as Windows wishes, in my case 1600x1200 (it didn't work at first because I was already on 1280x1024), then follow the screenshots:

### 1. Advanced Display Settings

[image]

### 2. Display Adaptor properties

[image]

### 3. List all modes

[image]

### 4. Select desired resolution

[image]

### 5. Apply and save everything

I hope this helps other people with similar issues

Comment: Well found, didn't even know this option exists. +1

Comment: Just changing the refresh rate seems to have done it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the free
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU):

> Custom Resolution Utility (CRU) is an EDID editor with a focus on custom resolutions. CRU shows you how the monitor defines resolutions and other capabilities and gives you the power to change it. Add custom resolutions, remove unwanted resolutions, edit FreeSync ranges, and more.

[Extended Display Identification Data (EDID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)
is the information where the monitor tells Windows what it can do.
Apparently, Windows does not understand this monitor, so this utility can forcefully
change how Windows sees it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it for using at work. We have very low resolution monitors and UI stuff takes way too much space in them leaving little space for actual work. I do realise pixel merging isn't the best option, but I'll give it a try :)